# Better display of boolean formulas

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I want to implement a method for showing a propositional formula in SML. The solutions that I found so far was of this type:

```
fun show (Atom a) = a
  | show (Neg p) = "(~ " ^ show p ^ ")"
  | show (Conj(p,q)) = "(" ^ show p ^ " & " ^ show q ^ ")"
  | show (Disj(p,q)) = "(" ^ show p ^ " | " ^ show q ^ ")";
```

This produces unnecessary braces:

```
((~p) & (q | r))
```

when, what I'd like to have is:

```
~ p & (q | r)
```

I saw, that Haskell has a function (display?) which does this nicely. Can someone help me out a little bit. How should I go about this?

Comment: Could you just drop off the first and last characters from the string when you're done building the representation?  You know it'll always have parentheses around it, so at the top level just do SML equivalent of `init . tail` on the output.

Comment: Not gona work, because the problem isn't in the outer most parantheres, but in the nested binary operators.

Comment: @RunoTheDog Where's the case for implication? (eg `->`)

Comment: I'm apologise. I posted the wrong example. There are no implications in the expressions, just the Atom, Neg, Conj and Disj constructors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to eliminate redundant parentheses, you will need to pass around some precedence information. For example, in Haskell, the `showsPrec` function embodies this pattern; it has type

```
showsPrec :: Show a => Int -> a -> String -> String
```

where the first `Int` argument is the precedence of the current printing context. The extra `String` argument is a trick to get efficient list appending. I'll demonstrate how to write a similar function for your type, though admittedly in Haskell (since I know that language best) and without using the extra efficiency trick.

The idea is to first build a string that has no top-level parentheses -- but does have all the parentheses needed to disambiguate subterms -- then add parentheses only if necessary. The `unbracketed` computation below does the first step. Then the only question is: when should we put parentheses around our term? Well, the answer to that is that things should be parenthesized when a low-precedence term is an argument to a high-precedence operator. So we need to compare the precedence of our immediate "parent" -- called `dCntxt` in the code below -- to the precedence of the term we're currently rendering -- called `dHere` in the code below. The `bracket` function below either adds parentheses or leaves the string alone based on the result of this comparison.

```
data Formula
    = Atom String
    | Neg  Formula
    | Conj Formula Formula
    | Disj Formula Formula

precedence :: Formula -> Int
precedence Atom{} = 4
precedence Neg {} = 3
precedence Conj{} = 2
precedence Disj{} = 1

displayPrec :: Int -> Formula -> String
displayPrec dCntxt f = bracket unbracketed where
    dHere       = precedence f
    recurse     = displayPrec dHere
    unbracketed = case f of
        Atom s   -> s
        Neg  p   -> "~ " ++ recurse p
        Conj p q -> recurse p ++ " & " ++ recurse q
        Disj p q -> recurse p ++ " | " ++ recurse q
    bracket
        | dCntxt > dHere = \s -> "(" ++ s ++ ")"
        | otherwise      = id

display :: Formula -> String
display = displayPrec 0
```

Here's how it looks in action.

```
*Main> display (Neg (Conj (Disj (Conj (Atom "a") (Atom "b")) (Atom "c")) (Conj (Atom "d") (Atom "e"))))
"~ ((a & b | c) & d & e)"
```

Comment: Unbracket return a formula without braces, right? But, can you please explain, how does the bracket function work?

Comment: @RunoTheDog Okay, I've added a paragraph; let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: I know the question was about boolean formulas, but note that this approach does only work for boolean formulas. If you want to extend to arithmetic it will fall down because + and - have the same precedence, similarly * and /, but if what you have is "(a-(b-c))", you can't print it as "a-b-c". Just precedence isn't enough for optimal printing of parentheses.