# Logic formula printing in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am dealing with some weird problem. I want to write a Haskell program, which will print given logical formulae, i.e.

```
print (showFormula (I (N (Z 'p')) (A (C (Z 'p') (Z 'q')) (Z 'r'))))
```

*(where I is implication, A - alternative, N - negation, C - conjunction and Z - character)*

should print something like that:

```
"(~p => ((p & q) | r))"
```

So far, my code looks like that:

```
data Formula
    = Z Char
    | V Bool
    | N Formula
    | C Formula Formula
    | A Formula Formula
    | I Formula Formula
    | Join Formula Formula

showFormula :: Formula -> String
showFormula (Z c) = [c]
showFormula (Join a b) = (showFormula a) ++ (showFormula b)

showFormula (N a) = '~':(showFormula a)
showFormula (C a b) = "("++(showFormula a)++" & "++(showFormula b)++")"
showFormula (A a b) = "("++(showFormula a)++" | "++(showFormula b)++")"
showFormula (I a b) = "("++(showFormula a)++" => "++(showFormula b)++")"
```

It does print proper string but only when you input simple formula like `(C (Z 'a') (Z 'b'))` and it crashes with some expanded formulae. I know that the problem is passing a Formula parameter instead of String to showFormula function, but I have no idea how to change that. Please give me some advices how to fix that.

Comment: You may also like [this question with a very similar goal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20406722/791604).

Comment: Note, by the way, that you can write infix constructors if they begin with a `:`, so you could have `Formula :&: Formula`, `Formula :|: Formula`, and `Formula :=> Formula instead of `C`, `A`, and `I`.  (You also may want fixity declarations then – perhaps `infixr 3 :&&:`, `infixr 2 :|:`, and `infixr 4 :=>`.)

Comment: Thank you @AntalS-Z, that's pretty handy, but C, A and I are required, because are generated by other program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compile your code with the `-Wall` flag it will show you the following warning:

```
fml.hs:4:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for `showFormula': Patterns not matched: V _
```

You forgot to write the `V` case for `showFormula` so it will crash if it reaches that, similarly to how the `head` function crashes if you call it with an empty list.

Comment: @user2342783: Thats not being dumb. Its just a beginner mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just missed the `(V b)` case in your pattern match.

```
data Formula
    = Z Char
    | V Bool
    | N Formula
    | C Formula Formula
    | A Formula Formula
    | I Formula Formula
    | Join Formula Formula

showFormula :: Formula -> String
showFormula (V b) = show b
showFormula (Z c) = [c]
showFormula (Join a b) = (showFormula a) ++ (showFormula b)

showFormula (N a) = '~':(showFormula a)
showFormula (C a b) = "("++(showFormula a)++" & "++(showFormula b)++")"
showFormula (A a b) = "("++(showFormula a)++" | "++(showFormula b)++")"
showFormula (I a b) = "("++(showFormula a)++" => "++(showFormula b)++")"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (showFormula (I (N (Z 'p')) (A (C (Z 'p') (Z 'q')) (Z 'r'))))
  -- "(~p => ((p & q) | r))"
```