# Is there something like cata but where you can match inner structure?

Tags: haskell, recursion, abstract-syntax-tree, catamorphism, recursion-schemes

I have this language AST

```
data ExprF r = Const Int
              | Var   String
              | Lambda String r
              | EList [r]
              | Apply r r
 deriving ( Show, Eq, Ord, Functor, Foldable )
```

And I want to convert it to string

```
toString = cata $ \case
  Const x -> show x
  Var x -> x
  EList x -> unwords x
  Lambda x y -> unwords [x, "=>", y]
  Apply x y -> unwords [x, "(", y, ")"]
```

But when lambda is used in `Apply` I need the parentheses

```
(x => x)(1)
```

but I cannot match inner structure with cata

```
toString :: Fix ExprF -> String
toString = cata $ \case
  Const x -> show x
  Var x -> x
  Lambda x y -> unwords [x, "=>", y]
  Apply (Lambda{}) y -> unwords ["(", x, ")", "(", y, ")"]
  Apply x y -> unwords [x, "(", y, ")"]
```

Is there any better solution than `para`?

```
toString2 :: Fix ExprF -> String
toString2 = para $ \case
  Const x -> show x
  Var x -> x
  Lambda x (_,y) -> unwords [x, "=>", y]
  EList x -> unwords (snd <$> x)
  Apply ((Fix Lambda {}),x) (_,y) -> unwords ["(", x, ")", "(", y, ")"]
  Apply (_,x) (_,y) -> unwords [x, "(", y, ")"]
```

It looks uglier. Even it is needed only in one place I need to remove fst tuple parameters everywhere and I guess it will be slower.

Comment: In the general case, you could take a precedence argument as in `showsPrec`. Para does not look too bad to me, though.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't see where I can put this argument. In this case yes `para` is ok, but when ast is much bigger it's just too much noise

Comment: @ais I don't have time to write a full answer right now, but you can pass a `Bool` down to the recursive call by folding to a function `Bool -> a`. [Kiselyov's tagless final notes](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/lecture.pdf) touch on it.

Comment: You could build a function using cata: something like `cata $ \case Var x -> const x ; Apply x y -> \_ -> unwords [x 5, y 5] ; Lambda x y -> (\p -> if p==5 then addParen (x 0) (y 0) else noParen (x 0) (y 0) ; ...` Adjust precedence numbers as needed, and pass an initial 0 at the top level so that the result is a string.

Comment: @ais You may like the discussion in [this question on pretty-printing boolean formulae](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20406722/791604) for more on the `showsPrec` approach.

Comment: @chi interesting. But why `Int`, Shouldn't `Bool` be enough?

Comment: One option is to wrap a newtype around `Fix ExprF`, then use pattern synonyms to construct/deconstruct it. The pattern synonyms will make it less awkward, and the newtype will make the types look less scary.

Comment: @ais Bool is fine if you only have two levels of precedence. In the general case, you need more. The link by Daniel Wagner above is such an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @chi, @DanielWagner and I pointed out in the comments, the way to do this sort of pretty-printing-with-parenthesisation in a structurally recursive manner is "the [`showsPrec`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:showsPrec) approach".

The big idea is not to fold up the syntax tree into a `String`, but into a *function* `Bool -> String`. This gives us a degree of context-sensitivity in the fold: we'll use that extra `Bool` parameter to keep track of whether we're currently in the context of the left-hand side of an application.

```
parens x = "(" ++ x ++ ")"

ppAlg :: ExprF (Bool -> String) -> (Bool -> String)
ppAlg (Const x) isBeingApplied = show x
ppAlg (Var x) isBeingApplied = x
ppAlg (Lambda name body) isBeingApplied = p ("\\" ++ name ++ " -> " ++ body False)
    where p = if isBeingApplied then parens else id
ppAlg (EList es) isBeingApplied = unwords (sequenceA es False)
ppAlg (Apply fun arg) isBeingApplied = fun True ++ " " ++ arg False
```

We pass values of `isBeingApplied` down the recursive calls depending on where we are in the syntax tree right now. Note that the only place we're passing down `True` is as an argument to `fun` in the body of the `Apply` case. Then, in the `Lambda` case, we inspect that argument. If the current term is the left-hand part of an application we parenthesise the lambda; if not we don't.

At the top level, having folded up the whole tree into a function `Bool -> String`, we pass it an argument of `False` - we're not currently in the context of an application - to get a `String` out.

```
pp :: Expr -> String
pp ex = cata ppAlg ex False

ghci> pp $ app (lam "x" (var "x")) (cnst 2)
"(\\x -> x) 2"
```

By replacing the `Bool` with an `Int`, this approach can be generalised to parenthesising operators with arbitrary precedences, as covered in [@DanielWagner's linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406722/better-display-of-boolean-formulas).

Comment: A function `Bool -> String` is just a pair `(String, String)`. So you fold it twice, with and without parentheses, then select which one you want during the recursion. That's brilliant, +1

Comment: @V.Semeria Yep! That's exactly right. The `Bool -> String` version is better though. You do less work (because you only _actually_ fold it once). It also scales better to syntaxes with more than two precedences: if you have, say, 5 precedence levels in your language then working with `Int`s (or some type with five values, if you wanna be total) is much easier than working with tuples `(String, String, String, String, String)`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the `{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}` extension and define unidirectional patterns like:

```
pattern Apply' r1 r2 <- Apply (_,r1) (_,r2)
```

that you could then use in your definitions like this:

```
toString2 :: Fix ExprF -> String
toString2 = para $ \case
  Const x -> show x
  Var x -> x
  Lambda x (_,y) -> unwords [x, "=>", y]
  EList x -> unwords (snd <$> x)
  Apply ((Fix Lambda {}),x) (_,y) -> unwords ["(", x, ")", "(", y, ")"]
  Apply' x y -> unwords [x, "(", y, ")"]
```

Since `ExprF` is a Functor, another option would be simply to write:

```
toString2' :: Fix ExprF -> String
toString2' = para $ \case
  Apply ((Fix Lambda {}),x) (_,y) -> unwords ["(", x, ")", "(", y, ")"]
  other -> case fmap snd other of
      Const x -> show x
      Var x -> x
      Lambda x y -> unwords [x, "=>", y]
      Apply x y -> unwords [x, "(", y, ")"]
```

With the pattern synonym, and compiling with `-Wall`, I'm having trouble convincing the exhaustivity checker that the pattern matches are exhaustive.

Comment: This makes the code shorter but it doesn't directly address the question. OP wants to use structural recursion to write the pretty-printer

Comment: The exhaustivity checker is completely broken with regard to pattern synonyms (or at least non-trivial ones). No one has a fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

How about straight recursion for the missing case :

```
toString :: Fix ExprF -> String
toString (Fix (Apply (Fix (Lambda _ x)) y)) = "(" ++ toString x ++ ")(" ++ toString y ++ ")"
toString z = (cata $ \case
  Const x -> show x
  Var x -> x
  EList x -> unwords x
  Lambda x y -> unwords [x, "=>", y]
  Apply x y -> unwords [x, "(", y, ")"]) z
```

Comment: This will fail since cata does not recurse using the first case e.g. in `Apply (Apply (Lambda ..) ..) ..`

Comment: Then a recursion for each ExprF constructor. It's not much longer than para and it will probably be faster.

Comment: I think the whole point of the question is about avoiding writing explicit recursion.

Comment: @DanielWagner not necessary. The main point is to find what could be a better solution for the problem.